# Unable to get access token from Facebook. Got an OAuthException says "Error validating verification code"

Tags: facebook, token

I am using java and the purpose of my demo application is simple: Update user status.
I followed the **Server-side Flow** on page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication. I got the auth dialog, facebook lead to the callback url and I got the **code** in my callback page. Then I failed when I try to generate an access token.

In the guide page, it says the following url could be used to generated an access token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
     client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&
     client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=THE_CODE_FROM_ABOVE
```

But what happens in my environment is I got the following error message:

```
{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "Error validating verification code."
   }
}
```

I am quite sure every parameter is correct because if I change the client_id value or client_secret parameter, I will got a different error message. The code parameter is what I got from facebook callback. So this should be correct, right? Really can't figure out what is the problem....

Any idea about this? I get stuck here...

Comment: Resolved this by my self...The key problem is all about "URL". The callback "redirect_uri" in code generation url should also be the same as "redirect_uri" in the token generation url...

Comment: Absolutely priceless. Thank you so much for that.

Comment: This is silly and should be mentioned in the docs. Thanks a lot for the info

Comment: This also helped me. Ridiculous it's not in the docs, i thought it had to be something different for it to redirect to after that step...

Comment: I am using the same uri, but its not working. By the way, I am using the redirect url with https, is that problem?

Comment: Masud, did you find a fix? I too am using the same URL

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I recently dealt with exactly this problem: everything matched, but it failed with the OAuthException.  The thing that made it work was to change the redirect uri (in both requests for the flow) from:

http://foo.example.com

to

http://foo.example.com/

I.e., add the trailing slash.  And then it worked.  Stupid and silly, but there you go.

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying to figure this out for ages. What a stupid problem.

Comment: where did you change the redirect uri? I don't see a setting for this on the app page on Facebook.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been banging my head on my desk for a while trying to figure this out.

Comment: This answer literally saved me 30 mins of horrible, horrible frustration.

Comment: For crying out loud! I have been stuck on this for hours and this fixed it. Thanks sir. Still annoying though.

Comment: OMG CHIP! You're awesome!

Comment: I faced a similar issue using passport-facebook module for Node.JS , by adding a '/' to the end of redirection URL the issue was solved .

Comment: Omg, I spent 3 hours trying to fix that and the solution was so simple! Can't believe the link in the Firebase is without the slash.

Comment: do you also need to change the Facebook application settings to add trailing slash?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and tried the above suggestions. They helped, but in my case the problem was that my redir URL had a query parameter and Facebook wasn't cool with that. So, moral of the story is that the redir url you sent to exchange the token has to be identical the the original redir url and it can't have query parameters.

Comment: Query parameters are OK, but they need to be the same when you make the second call to exchange the code for a token

Comment: I made sure that the two URLs were identical. They only worked when they were identical AND there were no query parameters. Also tried URL encoded un-encoded.

Comment: Use the state parameter to send whatever extra parameters you want to the redirected URL: Optional. An opaque string used to maintain application state between the request and callback. When Facebook redirects the user back to your redirect_uri, this value will be included unchanged in the response.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

Answer (score 3):

We had some fun with this as well.

In our case the trailing slash in the URL was already there, so I tried the Token we were using in the [FB Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and it validated, so it looked like FB wasn't even seeing the Token in the request.

After some investigation I found the head-slapper - we doing a GET with HTTP Headers only not with a Querystring, so FB litterally wasn't seeing the Token at all.

The moral seems to be that if you can get the Token to validated in the FB Debug tool, there is likely /something/ amiss in your request -

It might be a missing "/" or some other mismatch with the App's defined URL (Domain mistmatch is a different error). I have not tried defining the App / Web Url for HTTPS and doing the request with HTTP but I suspect it would also hiccup somehow.

Or as in our case, the Request Method might be incorrect - GET with Headers or POSTing both throw the 2500, you have to do GET with a Querystring.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.  It was a URL difference, but unlike the others that have posted, mine was the difference between HTTP and HTTPS.

We have BigIP handling HTTPS requests and forwarding over to an HTTP Apache server.  When BaseFacebook's getCurrentUrl() function was called, it detected HTTP, and not the original HTTPS.  I've modified that function like so:

```php
protected function getCurrentUrl() {
    if ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1)) ||
        (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') || 
        (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PSEUDOSSL']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_PSEUDOSSL'] == 'true')) {
      $protocol = 'https://';
    }
    else {
      $protocol = 'http://';
    }
...
```

This version supports the `HTTP_PSEUDOSSL` key.  I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the trailing slash worked for me too, thanks!

For debugging purposes, I found it helpful to use exactly the code fb provides on the developer page:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Once you get that working, you can modify it to fit your own code.

I'm not sure, but you might also check to make sure your "Site URL" and "Site Domain" settings are correct on the App Edit screen, because according to the documentation, the redirect_uri must be in the same domain.  (This is different from the canvas/tab page urls.)

Answer (score 0):

I was also having a url problem, but the solution to it is different.  I was passing the [`signedRequest`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) that the [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) returns to the server, and using the `code` value from that to request an access-token.  However, according to some comments in the 3.1.1 version of the [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/v3.1.1/src/base_facebook.php), the JavaScript SDK associates the `code` with a `redirect_uri` of empty string, i.e. `""`:

```php
// the JS SDK puts a code in with the redirect_uri of ''
if (array_key_exists('code', $signed_request)) {
    $code = $signed_request['code'];
    $access_token = $this->getAccessTokenFromCode($code, '');
    if ($access_token) {
       // etc
    }
}
```

After I changed my own server-side code to use a `redirect_uri` of `""`, then the request for an access-token worked.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, my code wasn't working on IE.
The issue was in the following line

```
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user_id)
```

Because somehow the getUser function always returned 0, so that condition was always true. Than he generated that error from invalid token.
Well, i fixed it by just saying this:

```
if ($user_id>0)
```

Silly stuff...