# Facebook.mobileLogin problem. "OAuthException" message: "Error validating application."

Tags: facebook, validation, facebook-actionscript-api

I try to login on facebook using facebook action script SDK.

```
FacebookMobile.init("my_app_id", initCallback);
private function initCallback(success:Object, fail:Object):void
        {
            trace("initCallback");
            trace("success: " + success);
            trace("fail" + fail);

            var appPermissions:Array = new Array("read_stream", "offline_access", "publish_stream", "read_friendlists");
            Facebook.mobileLogin("http://foo.example.com/", "touch", appPermissions);
        }

        private function loginCallback(success:Object, fail:Object):void
        {
            trace("loginCallback");
            trace("success: " + success);
            trace("fail" + fail);
        }
```

But I fail with error while calling mobileLogin:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating application.",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}
```

I read this answer, guys say it helps, but for me it was not successfull.
[Unable to get access token from Facebook. Got an OAuthException says "Error validating verification code"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001692/unable-to-get-access-token-from-facebook-got-an-oauthexception-says-error-valid)
How can I solve this, anybody help please. Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finded solution:

instead of using

```
Facebook.mobileLogin("http://foo.example.com/", "touch", appPermissions);
```

**I have used:**

```
FacebookMobile.login(loginCallback, appView.stage, appPermissions, null);
```

and now I got success on login, uid, and all my user information from facebook. Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Until you have added to your application Configuration a domain on which you application will be running from this will not work it seems. 
Here are some tips:

1) Define Domain on the Facebook Application configuration page.
2) add one website in this domain to the application by providing its address in Facebook Application configuration page.
3) add the meta tags on the page

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="FILL_YOUR_APPID"/>
```

with html declaration

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" 
    xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

3) Once you have done that head over to http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
enter your URL let Facebook cache register the page.