# Invalid verification code format error using scribe OAuth in android

Tags: android, facebook, oauth-2.0, scribe

i am using **scribe** oAuth library to implement Facebook  oAuth login , using
[this](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/FacebookExample.java) example

> I have set www.example.com (a valid ur) in Site URL and Mobile Web Url
>   in  facebook application setting

here is my code in android

```
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                                        .provider(FacebookApi.class)
                                        .apiKey(apiKey)
                                        .apiSecret(apiSecret)
                                        .callback("http://www.example.com/")
                                        .build();
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

          System.out.println("=== " + NETWORK_NAME + "'s OAuth Workflow ===");
          System.out.println();

          // Obtain the Authorization URL
          System.out.println("Fetching the Authorization URL...");
          String authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl(EMPTY_TOKEN);
          System.out.println("Got the Authorization URL!");
          System.out.println("Now go and authorize Scribe here:");
          System.out.println(authorizationUrl);
          System.out.println("And paste the authorization code here");
          System.out.print(">>");
          String val = new String();
          if(in.hasNextLine())
           val = in.nextLine();
          System.out.println("VALUE"+val);
          Verifier verifier = new Verifier(val);
          System.out.println();

          // Trade the Request Token and Verfier for the Access Token
          System.out.println("Trading the Request Token for an Access Token...");
          Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(EMPTY_TOKEN, verifier);
          System.out.println("Got the Access Token!");
          System.out.println("(if your curious it looks like this: " + accessToken + " )");
          System.out.println();
```

**but i am getting following error**

```
Caused by: org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract a token from this: '{"error":{"message":"Invalid verification code format.","type":"OAuthException"}}'
```

**Logcat**

```
: === Facebook's OAuth Workflow === : Fetching the Authorization URL... : Got the Authorization URL! : Now go and authorize Scribe here: : https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F : And paste the authorization code here : >>VALUE  Trading the Request Token for an Access Token... GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5523 objects / 320760 bytes in 81ms AndroidRuntime(541): Shutting down VM : threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)  FATAL EXCEPTION: main  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.commauth/com.commauth.CommonAuthActivity}: org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract a token from this: '{"error":{"message":"Invalid verification code format.","type":"OAuthException"}}'
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  Caused by: org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract a token from this: '{"error":{"message":"Invalid verification code format.","type":"OAuthException"}}'
     at org.scribe.extractors.TokenExtractor20Impl.extract(TokenExtractor20Impl.java:33)
     at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth20ServiceImpl.getAccessToken(OAuth20ServiceImpl.java:37)
     at com.commauth.CommonAuthActivity.onCreate(CommonAuthActivity.java:57)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
     ... 11 more
```

IF i run this as a standalone program then it asks me for some authorization code 
but i really don't know wht to put in there.

here at the code line

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Verifier verifier = new Verifier(in.nextLine());
System.out.println();
```

Comment: @Alexei , ya m still stuck there only , i tried on a Facebook Forum too but still didn't get any replay

Comment: "it asks me for some authorization code"

This is scribe saying: "Go to this URL" (given at this line: `System.out.println(authorizationUrl);`) "and Facebook should ask you whether you want to authorize this application. Authorize it and Facebook will give you a code. Paste that here:"

Does that make sense? I imagine it'd be the same on android powered devices. But maybe not, and that could be the reason you're getting that error. Sorry, I don't know how to fix that problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a slash at the end of your callback url.  I spent a few HOURS troubleshooting this!!!  Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001692/unable-to-get-access-token-from-facebook-got-an-oauthexception-says-error-vali) I found the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and in fact, I just see that the code that I was entering was not correct. When I was copiyng it from the navigator address, it didn't copy the whole code (too big ?). So double check if the code is the good one.