# Facebook authorization looping / Error validating verification code

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I have the follow code to login with Facebook:

```
// Include Facebook SDK

$this->facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'APP ID',
    'secret' => 'APP SECRET',
    'cookie' => true
));

$uid = $this->facebook->getUser();
if($uid) {
    try {
        echo 'Done!';
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo $e;
        error_log($e);
    }
} else {
    $loginUrl = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://ogabrielsantos.com.br/dev/index.php?route=account/connect/facebook',
        'scope' => 'user_birthday'
    ));

    echo('<script>top.location.href = "' . $loginUrl . '";</script>');
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

I can authorize the App, but, after authorization, I can't get the logged user, EVER redirecting to

```
http://ogabrielsantos.com.br/dev/index.php?route=account%2Fconnect%2Ffacebook&state=RANDOM STATE&code=RANDOM CODE#_=_
```

**I have tried:**

- Put the APP in a server;
- Verify APP settings. All is correct;
- Verify if url is the same at settings and code. All is ok;
- My url is properly written: `http://ogabrielsantos.com.br/dev/index.php?route=account/connect/facebook`;
- Reset APP SECRET.

Nothing worked.

You can check what happens going to:

`http://ogabrielsantos.com.br/dev/index.php?route=account/connect/facebook`

Facebook ask you to authorize the app to get your website, which is a safe information.

**UPDATE 2**

The follow code:

```
$this->facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $this->connect->config->get('facebook_api_key'),
    'secret' => $this->connect->config->get('facebook_app_secret'),
    'cookie' => true
));

$uid = $this->facebook->getUser();

echo'<pre>';
print_r($this->facebook);
echo'</pre>';
exit;
```

returns:

```
Facebook Object
(
    [sharedSessionID:protected] => 
    [appId:protected] => APP ID
    [appSecret:protected] => APP SECRET
    [user:protected] => 0
    [signedRequest:protected] => 
    [state:protected] => 
    [accessToken:protected] => APP ID|APP SECRET
    [fileUploadSupport:protected] => 
    [trustForwarded:protected] => 
)
```

I think the `accessToken` is wrong, returning my `APP ID` and `SECRET` with a pipeline separator.

**UPDATE 3:**

Now, I verify the code, but, always get `Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating verification code`

```
if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $api = $this->facebook->api('/oauth/access_token', array(
        'client_id' => APP ID,
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://ogabrielsantos.com.br/dev/index.php?route=account/connect/facebook',
        'client_secret' => APP SECRET,
        'code' => $_GET['code']
    ));

    echo'<pre>';
    var_dump($api);
    print_r($this->facebook->getUser());
    echo'</pre>';
    exit;
}
```

*I have read some questions, which is similar but can't help-me.*

Comment: after you authorized the user, you can get user info through graph api or fql. did you try those? or you dont get the uid?

Comment: @AtaurRahimChowdhury `$this->facebook->getUser();` always return `(int) 0`

Comment: @AtaurRahimChowdhury Get `Error validating verification code.` from OAUTH

Comment: Dio you ahve any other session management that may interfere with the Facebook's use of sessions?

Comment: @Robbie I have the follow FB session: `[fb_305590342814484_state] => e821eb187f8c0105e554fee33a48efea`, so, I think this is not the problem.

Comment: you may want to look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001692/unable-to-get-access-token-from-facebook-got-an-oauthexception-says-error-vali according to this post, can you try the redirect uri like this, 'http://localhost/Faanart/' only

Comment: @AtaurRahimChowdhury Always getting the looping

Comment: Nothing worked. Please, see my updated question =)

Answer (score 1):

Are you working on localhost? if yes it probably is the reason why.
If not, check your app settings in developers.facebook.com/apps/APP_ID
1. You have to compare the urls written in your code with the ones you have in your app settings.
2. Another reason could be the that the urls in you app settings are not properly written, I remember having to add index.php at the end of my urls in **Page Tab settings**. Worked for me
3. Another option is to get a new APP_SECRET and update your code
These options are from my personal experience, you issue could also be something else but you lose nothing trying

Comment: If you can't get a user id, it means that the issue is in your App settings. Unfortunately, I don't know what it is and I can only tell you about what I've experienced

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook Sharing and Facebook Sign In functions are completely separate and each require their own app.

Are you using facebook sharing in the page you want the login working on?

Ref: http://www.ning.com/help/?p=8523